Linear algebra question: does it have a solution?
Given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $p$ a prime number, $s = (s_1, s_2,..., s_{2k+1})\in \mathbb{M}_{(2k+1)*1}(\mathbb{F}_p)$, the Hankel matrix generated by $s$ is denoted as $H$ where
$$
H = \begin{pmatrix}
s_1 & s_2 & \cdots & s_{k+1} \\
s_2 & s_3 & \cdots & s_{k+2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
s_{k+1} & s_{k+2} & \cdots & s_{2k+1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Suppose that $H$ is of full rank.
Question: do there exist $c = (n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{k+1})\in\mathbb{M}_{1*(k+1)}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $b = (b_1,b_2,\dots, b_{k+1})^T\in\mathbb{M}_{(k+1)*1}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that the following system holds:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
n_1 & n_2 & \cdots & n_{k+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n_1^{2k} & n_2^{2k} & \cdots & n_{k+1}^{2k}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2\\ \vdots\\b_{k+1} 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
s_1\\s_2\\\vdots\\\vdots\\s_{2k+1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
I have a feeling that there do exist solutions, but I don't know how to connect the full-rank property of $H$ to the existence of this system.

I did. For instance, let $k = 2$, and $p = 7$. Then we have $c = (5,6,3), b = (1,4,2)^T$ as one of the solutions for $s=(0,0,1,0,0)$.

You are correct in most of the cases, for $p<k$, there could be no solution as you pointed out. For $n_i, b_i$ coming from extension fields, or the algebraic closure there definitely has solutions. But that's out of the scope, the definition of linear complexity of the sequence is indeed interesting, do you have any idea on how to relate this to the existence of solutions to NB = S?

The problem is related to but not an exact match with linear complexity of sequences. I try and reuse some of the algebraic machinery from that theory as I recall it.
My observation. The example sequence suggested by @xxxxxxxxx, namely $s_{k+1}=1$, $s_i=0$ whenever $i\neq k+1$, is a counterexample unless $k+1$ is a factor of $p-1$.
The matrix $H$ has then all ones on the wrong diagonal and zeros elsewhere, so it has full rank.
It is worth noting that in the case $k=2$, $p=7$, where Youzhe Heng verified the existence of a solution, we do have $k+1=3$, $p-1=6$ and therefore also $k+1\mid p-1$.
I think of this result only as a beginning of the full study of this problem. As an answer it is thus unsatisfactory, but them's the breaks. On with the story. Obviously
everything needs to be double-checked.
We turn a sequence $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ of entries from $\Bbb{F}_p$ into a power series
$$A(T)=a_1+a_2T+a_3T^2+\cdots\in \Bbb{F}_p[[T]].$$
We apply this only to sequences of length $2k+1$ that appear as columns of the matrix equation in the question. What this means is that we only know the terms up to degree $T^{2k}$. So we need to keep in mind that we only know the resulting power series modulo the ideal $I=T^{2k+1}\Bbb{F}_p[[T]]$. Effectively, I will be doing the arithmetic in the quotient ring $R:=\Bbb{F}_p[[T]]/I$.
With a fixed element $n\in\Bbb{F}_p$ we associate the sequence $(1,n,n^2,n^3,\ldots)$. This then yields the geometric series
$$G_n(T)=1+nT+n^2T^2+n^3T^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-nT}\in\Bbb{F}_p[[T]].$$
Let us fix a subset $M=\{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{k+1}\}\subseteq\Bbb{F}_p$ of $k+1$
distinct elements. The question is whether we can choose the set $M$ in such a way that the series
$$
S(T)=s_1+s_2T+\cdots+s_{2k+1}T^{2k}
$$
or rather, its coset in the quotient ring $R$, lies in the $\Bbb{F}_p$ span
$$
V(M)=\langle G_n(T)\mid n\in M\rangle_{\Bbb{F}_p}\subseteq R.
$$
I will need the following idea from the theory of linear complexity (in the context of the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm it is called the key equation), characterizing the elements of the space $V(M)$.
Lemma. Denote
$$F_M(T)=\prod_{n\in M}(1-nT).$$
If $R(T)\in V(M)$, then there exists a polynomial $Q(T)$ of degree $\le k$ such that
$$
F_M(T)R(T)\equiv Q(T)\pmod I.\tag{1}
$$
Proof. The set of polynomials of degree $\le k$ is closed under linear combinations, so it suffices to check (1) for the generating elements $G_n(T), n\in M$. But, if we fix an element $n'\in M$, then
$$G_{n'}(T)F_M(T)=\frac{F_M(T)}{1-n'T}=\prod_{n\in M, n\neq n'}(1-nT),$$
which is a polynomial of degree $\le k=|M|-1.$ QED
At long last we are ready for the proof of my observation. In the example situation we have
$$S(T)=T^k.$$
Assume that we can find a set $M\subseteq \Bbb{F}_p$ of size $k+1$ such that the OP's equation has a solution. In other words, we assume that $S(T)\in V(M)$. We
have $\deg F_M(T)\le k+1$ (this is actually an equality unless $0\in M$). The key equation $(1)$ thus promises the existence of a polynomial $Q(T)$ of degree $\le k$
such that
$$T^k F_M(T)\equiv Q(T)\pmod{T^{2k+1}}.$$
Remembering that the constant term of $F_M(T)$ is equal to $1$, the special shape of the factor $T^k$ then forces $F_M(T)$ to be of the form
$$
F_M(T)=1+a T^{k+1}\tag{2}
$$
for some $a\in\Bbb{F}_p$. The case $a=0$ is uninteresting (then $M=\{0\}$ and $k=1$), so we can conclude that $0\notin M$. As $1/n$ is a zero of $F_M(T)$ for every $n\in M$, $(2)$  implies that the equation
$$
1+a x^{k+1}=0\equiv x^{k+1}=-1/a\tag{3}
$$
has $k+1$ distinct solutions in the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$. The ratio of any two solutions $x,x'$ of $(3)$ satisfies $(x/x')^{k+1}=1$. So for $(3)$ to have $k+1$
solutions in the prime field, we need the said prime field to contain a primitive root of unity of order $k+1$. Such a primitive root is well known to exist if and only if $k+1\mid p-1$.

Some concluding remarks:

In Youzhe Heng's solution for the special $s$-sequence in the case $k=2$, $p=7$, the variables $n_i$ were exactly the third roots of unity $1,2,4$ in $\Bbb{F}_7$. This aligns well enough with my findings.
A small test case to verify my observation would be to brute force $k=2$, $p=11$. Again with the $s$-sequence $(0,0,1,0,0)$. I claim that no solutions exist.
If $k+1\mid p-1$, then our special example $s$-sequence is NOT a counterexample. We can use the prescribed roots of unity as the set $M$. The first $k+1$ equations then have a unique solution to $b_i$s (Vandermonde, or Discrete Fourier Transform). In other words, if $\zeta\in\Bbb{F}_p$ is a primitive root of unity of order $k+1$,
we can use $n_j=\zeta^{j-1}$ for all $j, 1\le j\le k+1$. Then the first $k+1$ equations look like
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&\zeta&\zeta^2&\cdots&\zeta^k\\
1&\zeta^2&\zeta^{2\cdot2}&\cdots&\zeta^{2k}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&\zeta^k&\zeta^{2k}&\cdots&\zeta^{k\cdot k}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
b_1\\ b_2\\ b_3 \\ \vdots \\ b_{k+1}
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
s_1\\ s_2\\ s_3 \\ \vdots \\ s_{k+1}
\end{array}\right).
$$
As this time the coeffiecient matrix is Vandermonde type square matrix, this smaller system has a unique solution. A key ingredient is that when we extend the system to $2k+1$ equations, the next $k$ equations will simply repeat the top $k$ equations. Due to powers of $\zeta$ as well as the $s_i$s repeating with period $k+1$.


Linear complexity of sequences is all about finding recurrence relations matching the key equation $(1)$. In the general situation the feedback polynomial $F_M(T)$ can have zeros outside the field of interest (here the prime field). Also repeated roots may be necessary. That is why the general machinery (Berlekamp-Massey) doesn't quite work here.

The geometric series are the ones determined by a recurrence relation of depth one, so linear complexity $=1$. Here the question is more specifically about feedback polynomials with simple roots, all in the prime field.

Thanks a lot for all the effort. Indeed, I checked for the case $k=2, p = 11$ and $k=2, p = 17$ ($s=(0,0,1,0,0)$), and they all have no solution. The last part I did not quite get, does it mean that for case $k+1|p-1$, it always has solution? BTW, what's still missing is the general case. We don't know yet for an arbitrary full-rank H, $S(T)\in V(M)$ or not.

@YouzheHeng I added a more detailed explanation to the last bullet. You can further test this with $k=2$, $p=19$, $s=(0,0,1,0,0)$, $(n_1,n_2,n_3)=(1,7,11)$, as $7$ and $7^2\equiv11$ are the third roots unity modulo $p=19$.

Correct. What is missing from the general case is a description of the $s$-sequences allowing a solution. We need the $s$-sequence to obey a recurrence relation with a feedback polynomial $F_M(T)$ of degree $\le k+1$ and roots in the prime field. But that's a kludgy of putting it to say the least :-).

for $k=2, p=19, s =(0,0,1,0,0), (1, 7, 11)$, the solution is $(15,13,10)^T$.

Just some notes. We'll shift the indexing by $1$, that is, we are dealing with the $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ Hankel matrix
$(s_{i+j})_{0\le i,j\le k}$.  The question can be rephrased as: is $(s_i)_{0\le i \le 2k}$ the initial piece of an infinite linear recurrence sequence of order $k+1$, whose recurrence has distinct roots (in the ground field $F$).  One sees easily that this is equivalent to: there exists $\color{red}{y}\colon = \color{red}{s_{2k+1}}$ such that the determinant of the $(k+2) \times (k+2)$ matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} s_0 & s_1 & \ldots & s_{k+1} \\
                     s_1 & s_2 & \ldots & s_{k+2} \\
                   \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
                   s_k & s_{k+1} & \ldots &  \color{red}{s_{2k+1}}\\
                   \color{blue}{ 1} & \color{blue}{ \ldots} & \color{blue}{ t^k} &  \color{blue}{ t^{k+1}} \end{pmatrix}$$
as a polynomial in $\color{blue}{ t}$ ( of degree $k+1$, mind you), has all roots distinct and in $F$.
Notes:

The case $k=1$ and char $=p\ne 2$ this all works OK.

What the field $F$ is seems important.  For instance, $F$ algebraically closed of characteristic $0$  would probably give an answer Yes. Also, haven't seen a case with $F=\mathbb{R}$ that does not work.

One should look at Polya and Szego vol. 2, VII &2 for results on the connection between Hankel determinants and (rational) power series.

The answer is similar to the one of Jyrki.


$\bf{Added:}$ Consider the above polynomial
$$P(t) =P_{k+1}(t) + y Q_{k}(t)$$
with $\deg P_{k+1}(t) = k+1$, $\deg Q_k(t) \le k$. We are interested whether there are values of $y$ such that $P(t)$ has all roots distinct.  Now  this shouldn't happen if ( and only if -- a Hail Mary) the polynomials $P_{k+1}(t)$ and $Q_k(t)$ have a common $double$ root. One can look at their resultant.  For $k\ge 3$ it is quite a monster, however, for $k=2$, it is the fourth power (!) of $\det (s_{i+j})_{0\le i,j\le 2} \ne 0$, as one can check. So that takes care of the case $k=2$, and $F$ algebraically closed.
For $k=3$ the resultant is hard to handle. Note that we should use in fact the "second" resultant ( $\exists$ common factor of degree $2$, and with a double root at that). So that could imply again $\det = 0$
